# Sql or Connection string issue ? asp.net mvc 4 tutorials

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm having a continuous issues when it comes to database creation and access when trying out mvc 4 tutorials. The latest for example http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4. I've got to the point where I'm trying to use EF Code First Migrations to migrate some changes to the model classes so the change is applied to the database. And dummy data seeded to the database.
When I run "update-database" after entering "add-migration Initial" I get ....

```
  Cannot open database "_Movies.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
  Login failed for user 'USER\me'
```

When I check SQL server management studio, my name is listed in the Logins folder, within Security folder. Is there anything else I can check ? Still learning, so please explain answers.

Connection string if needed...

```
  <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=_Movies.mdf;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\_Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: You need to ensure you have permissions on the database or that your database role is set to sysadmin.  To verify database permissions, open your user login from the Security folder (double click) and then click on the User Mapping option on the left side of the Login properties window.  From there, you will get a list of databases and permissions for each one (only need to do this if you are not set to sysadmin role).  To check server role, click on Server Roles from left pane

Comment: "One or more databases are inaccessible and will not be displayed in list"........of course the one I need is not listed ?

Comment: Its most likely because it isnt attached.  Try to ensure you are a sql admin (using the server roles)

Comment: Within Server Role my name is listed under Role Members, do I just highlight and click add ?

Comment: Go to security -> Logins.  Double click your name (which opens a new window).  In that new window, click Server Roles.  Ensure public/sysadmin are checked.  Click OK. :)